# How to check if the same element is present before current element but that doesn't share the same parent?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

From person of id A in `<listOfPerson>`, is it possible to check if there is a "person" before ?

In this case, it should be true since there is a person in `<singlePerson>`

counting the preceding-sibling doesn't work here because they don't share the same parent, i'm not sure what alternative exists

thank you

```
<root>
    <singlePerson>
        <person>Z</person>
    </singlePerson>
    <listOfPerson>
        <person>A</person>
        <person>B</person>
        <person>C</person>
    </listOfPerson>
</root>
```

XSL :

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:variable name="persons" select="descendant::person"/>
    <!-- on person B of <listPerson> -->
    <xsl:value-of select="boolean(($persons[3]/following::person))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Output : true

Why does it return true instead of false ? There is no element containing a person after `<listOfPerson>`

following seems to be refering to **person C** because it returns false when I delete it but why? I'm not using following-sibling I'm confused

Comment: Use the `preceding` axis? https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#axes

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, i've edited the code. I don't understand the output using following

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Starting from B, the preceding axis contains A, Z (until you turn it into a node set by doing anything with it except using a node selector, at which point it would become Z, A) -- and the following axis contains C.

In addition to preceding and following, there are also preceding-sibling and following-sibling.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:variable name="persons" select="descendant::person"/>
    <!-- on person B of <listPerson> -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$persons[3]/preceding::person[1]"/>
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>    <xsl:for-each select="$persons[3]/preceding::person">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>----</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$persons[3]"/>
    <xsl:text>----</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="$persons[3]/following::person">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="$persons[3]/preceding-sibling::person">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>====</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$persons[3]"/>
    <xsl:text>====</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="$persons[3]/following-sibling::person">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives this output:

```
A
ZA----B----C
A====B====C
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, quite simply, from the context of `root` the expression `descendant::person` selects **all** `person` elements that are descendants of `root` - including person Z. You can verify this by checking the value of `count($persons)` which will return 4.

Therefore the expression `$persons[3]` refers to person B - which is also easily verifiable by:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$persons[3]"/>
```

so naturally `$persons[3]/following::person` is person C - again proved by:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$persons[3]/following::person"/>
```